# Use HTML Div to add border only on top and bottom?

Tags: html

I use HTML DIV tag to format my header with border like this:

```
<h3 style="background-color:red; padding:2% 0 2% 0; border:5px solid green">
This is a header
</h3>
```

However, I would like to have the border appears only on top and bottom, but not on left and right. I would like border in the same way as padding for top left bottom and right, but border does not have this feature(or I don't know?). Is there any way in CSS style to do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just a case of:

```
<h3 style="background-color:red; padding:2% 0 2% 0; border-top:5px solid green; border-bottom: 5px solid green;">
This is a header
</h3>
```

Comment: Isn't there a shorthand?,I tried something like  `border: 5px solid green initial 5px solid green initial`. It didn't work

Answer (score 55):

For future reference, the following is a an alternative method that avoids having to define border properties (colour, width) more than once and allows declarations similar to those used for margin and padding (as requested).

```
border: 5px green;
border-style: solid none;
```

As with margin or padding, `border-style` is defined in order of top, right, bottom, left. The above case applies a solid border to top and bottom of an element and no border to the left or right of the element.

Using this method avoids creating redundancies in the declaration.

Comment: I think this is the best solution because it avoids duplication.

Comment: Just what I was looking for! +1

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following in your css or style tag ....

```
#div-id {
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px 0;
border-color: #000;
}
```

Using the border-width selector you can define the various border thickness. The values are inserted in the order top, right, bottom, left and the shorthand version is top/bottom and right/left which is what I've used.

For example, you can set a div with a 4px top border, a 3px right border, a 2px bottom border and a 1px left border with the following .... border-width: 4px 3px 2px 1px;

You can set both top and bottom borders to 3px and the left and right borders to 1 px with the following .... border-width: 3px 1px;

Answer (score 4):

`border-top: 5px solid green; border-bottom: 5px solid green;`

You should put this style directly on the `<h3>` rather than wrapping a div around it.

Comment: Nice. It works in w3schools interactive page: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_div_test

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `border-right` `border-left` ...  separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify border like so:

```
<h3 style="background-color:red; padding:2% 0 2% 0; 
           border-top:5px solid green; border-bottom:5px solid green">
    This is a header
</h3>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `border-left`, `border-right`, `border-top` and `border-bottom` properties to give different border styles to each side of your container.

In your case, you want to apply your style to `border-top` and `border-bottom`.